# Why Can't we define the differentiation of vector fields in the same way as in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, definition

In $\mathbb{R^{n}}$, if $X$ is a vector field on $\mathbb{R^{n}}$, and $X=$$\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}$ $X^{i}$ $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$, $X^{i}$ $\in$$C^{\infty}(p)$.

Then

1.*The differentiation of vector fields $X$ along a given vector $v$* $\in$ $T_{p}(\mathbb{R^{n}})$,denoted by $D_{v}X$ ,can be defined as :

$D_{v}X$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}$ $(D_{v}X^{i})$ $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$ , where $D_{v}X^{i}$ is just the *directional derivative* in the common sense.

2.Given two vector fields on $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ , X and V , we can define a new vector field $D_{V}X$ on $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ as:

$(D_{V}X)(p)$ = $D_{V(p)}X$ , where $D_{V(p)}X$ is defeined as above.

So my question is that :can we do the same thing to abstract manifolds ,namely,given two vector fields  X and V on manifold  M ,we get a new vector field $D_{V}X$ in the way listed above.

PS:I have been told that the answer is no ,because the new vector field $D_{V}X$ can not be defined globaly .But I don't know the reason.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On manifolds, the objects $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ are only defined locally, on each chart; recall that the $x^i$ are the coordinate functions of the local chart. So on each chart, which is after all diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can make the definition you suggest. However, there is no guarantee that on the intersection of two charts, the two definitions you make agree. Unless you do get agreement on overlaps, you haven't defined a global vector field.

The problem goes away in $\mathbb{R}^n$ because you have at atlas consisting of a single chart, so there are no overlaps to be checked.

Comment: I get it, thanks.